# mern-cli installation failed

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, mern

I follow the instructions in [mern.io](http://mern.io/) to install mern-cli on Macbook Pro:

```
sudo npm install -g mern-cli
```

But I got the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b 0.0.2 git://github.com/timoxley/next-tick.git /var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5e86851e
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5e86851e': Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2017-06-18T06_17_12_022Z-debug.log
```

Any idea?

Comment: It seems a problem of mern-cli itself, as I tried mean-cli works perfectly on my computer.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the complete log as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem of mern-cli itself, as I tried mean-cli works perfectly on my computer.